# python3 How to enable the function that print the singly-link list elements by type it's name

Tags: python, python-3.x, singly-linked-list

As you known, the list elements can be print by typing list variable name, So I want to achieve the function that can print the singly-link list elements same with list done.

```
class Node():
    """create node"""
    def __init__(self, elem):
        self.elem = elem
        self.next = None  

class SingleLinkList():
    """create singly-linked list"""
    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self.__head = node

    def add(self, item):
    '''add elements in the list header'''
    node = Node(item)
    node.next = self.__head
    self.__head = node

l1 = SingleLinkList()
l1.add(2)
l1.add(3)

#when type print(l1) instead of l1.some_function(), the terminal will show the elements in the l1 from head to tail
print(l1)
......
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please RTM: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to implement the [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method.

try this:

```py
class Node():
    """create node"""

    def __init__(self, elem):
        self.elem = elem
        self.next = None


class SingleLinkList():
    """create singly-linked list"""

    def __init__(self, node=None):
        self.__head = node

    def add(self, item):
        """add elements in the list header"""
        node = Node(item)
        node.next = self.__head
        self.__head = node

    def __str__(self):
        elems = []
        node = self.__head
        while node:
            elems.append(str(node.elem))
            node = node.next
        return ', '.join(elems)


l1 = SingleLinkList()
l1.add(2)
l1.add(3)

print(l1)
```

Output:

> 3, 2